# reactjs How to display filtered data in the table?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I display the filtered data in the table? the things I did before posted the question here is I already finish the filter, I can retrieve data from the database, and I'm sure it is working because I can see it using the console, my problem is I don't know how to display it inside the table. I am stuck here. thanks.

**Note**: ***the data will display after the user uses the filter.***

```
//header
.....
function createData(datetime, user, appCode, module, transaction, table, id, record) {
  return { datetime, user, appCode, module, transaction, table, id, record };
}
//this is were i need to display the data in `const rows`
const rows = [
  //this is where i want to post or display may data
  createData('July 22, 2021 | 07:34:12 AM', 'John Doe', 'App', 'Module', 'Transaction', 'Table','ID', 'Record'),
];

const AuditLogs = () => {
  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState("");
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [reason, setReason] = useState("");
  const [app, setApp] = useState("");
  const [transaction, setTransaction] = useState("");
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(10);
  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };
  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
    setPage(0);
  };
  const handleChangeTransaction = (event) => {
    setTransaction(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleChangeApp = (event) => {
    setApp(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleUpdateButton = async ()=>{
    const filter = await getaudit(app, transaction);
    //console.log(filter)
    setFiltered(filter)
    if (filter.status == 200){
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Successful.',
        text: 'Group has been successfully added.',
      })
    }else{
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Oops',
        text: 'Something went wrong.',
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <div style={{height: 'auto', width: '100%', padding: 8, backgroundColor: '#fffS'}}>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6}>
            <h4 style={{margin: 8}}>Audit Logs</h4> 
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={9} md={4} lg={4}>
            <TextField
              id="standard-full-width"
              // style={{ minHeight: 22, marginBottom: 4 ,}}
              placeholder="Search"
              fullWidth
              margin="dense"
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={3} md={2} lg={2} style={{padding: 8}}>
            <div className={classes.root}>
              <IconButton aria-label="delete" color="primary" >
                <SearchRoundedIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton aria-label="delete" color="primary">
                <CloudDownloadSharpIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid container xs={12} sm={10} md={10} lg={10}
                direction="row"
                justifyContent="center"
                alignItems="center">
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={6} style={{padding: 15, paddingBottom: 0, alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <DateRangePickerComponent id="daterangepicker" placeholder='Select a range' //startDate={} endDate={} 
              style={{paddingTop: 10, fontSize: 16}}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={6} style={{padding: 15, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="age-native-simple">Application</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={app}
                onChange={handleChangeApp}
              >
                <MenuItem  value="EAM">EAM</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="DMS">DMS</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="HRIS">HRIS</MenuItem>
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={6} style={{padding: 15, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="age-native-simple">Transaction</InputLabel>
              <Select
                fullWidth
                value={transaction}
               onChange={handleChangeTransaction}
              >
                <MenuItem value="Insert">Insert</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="Delete">Delete</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="Update">Update</MenuItem>
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container xs={12} sm={2} md={2} lg={2}
                direction="row"
                justifyContent="center"
                alignItems="center">
            <Grid item xs={12} style={{padding: 8}}>
              <Button onClick={handleUpdateButton} variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth>
                Apply Filters
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
      <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {columns.map((column) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={column.id}
                  align={column.align}
                  style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }}
                >
                  {column.label}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((row) => {
              return (
                <TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={row.code}>
                  {columns.map((column) => {
                    const value = row[column.id];
                    return (
                      <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align}>
                        {column.format && typeof value === 'number' ? column.format(value) : value}
                      </TableCell>
                    );
                  })}
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <TablePagination
        rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 100]}
        component="div"
        count={rows.length}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        onPageChange={handleChangePage}
        onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
      />
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

this is the result I get from the filtered

[image]

Update: I get this error by adding this code

```
        {filtered.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((row) => {
                   console.log(filtered)
                   console.log("ss", filtered.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage))
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're already mapping over the rows to display them.  How specifically is this not working?  What is the resulting DOM markup?  Are there any errors on the console?

Comment: no, I dont have error in the console, and yes I can filtered the data from the database , my problem is I dont know how to display it in the table, `const row`

Comment: But that's what isn't clear about the problem.  It looks like you *do* know how to display data.  You have an array called `rows` and you `.map()` over that array, returning JSX for each row.  What specifically isn't working?  Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: Ahh, I used it to display the data from the `const row` , The problem is i do not know how to display the data FROM the database.

Comment: In my `conts row` I have this message ```this is where i want to post or display may data```

Comment: Where in your code are you getting that data?  If you're just asking how to use a database then that has little to do with React or displaying data or pretty much anything in the question.  Please clarify the specific problem.

Comment: Maybe your results are in the `filtered` state variable?  Try mapping over `filtered.data` instead of `rows`.  (You may want to make sure `filtered.data` exists before using it though, since you initialize it to an empty string instead of an object.)

Comment: I will update my question

Answer (score 0):

You're mapping over `rows`, which appears to be fake data.  And it looks like your real data is in `filtered`, which you never use.

First, initialize `filtered` to something which matches your intended structure.  `rows` is an array, to make `filtered` an array as well:

```
const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);
```

When you call `setFiltered`, give it specifically the array of data that you want:

```
setFiltered(filter.data || []);
```

(Just in case the response is an error or in some way fails and `data` isn't there, this will default to an empty array.  Handle errors separately.)

Then in your rendering, use `filtered` instead of `rows` (which you no longer need):

```
{filtered.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((row) => {
  //...
})}
```

Comment: ```TypeError: filtered.slice(...).map is not a function```

Comment: @kaito: Just before that line, do `console.log(filtered)` and see what it outputs.  It should just be an array.

Comment: Where line? inside the filtered.slice?

Comment: @kaito: Immediately before the component's `return` that returns all of the JSX.

Comment: I got no return because of this error `TypeError: filtered.slice(...).map is not a function`

Comment: @kaito: In the code shown the only use of `.slice` is in the overall JSX render operation for the whole component.  That entire render operation is a single `return` statement for the component function.  Just before that `return` statement you can log the contents of that variable.  If, on the other hand, *that* `return` statement isn't being reached because of an error then either the error or the code is different from what you're showing.

Comment: Okay, I will post an image

Comment: @kaito: Also, if `.map()` is what's throwing the error, log the result of `filtered.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)` to the console as well.